# Multiple jquery paths leads to page slowdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a responsive page created by jquery, php and ajax. The same page loads content from another php page based on the selected LI. I have this working fine. The php page includes other php pages depending on the LI selected. Do i need to include the CSS & jquery on all the php pages too? Including the script path in all the pages makes the response very slow.

Main Page:

```
<UL>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<UL>
```

PHP page where the LI selection is checked and includes the other php page:

```
if(isset($_POST['li'])){

    $li = $_POST['li'];

    if($li=='1'){
        include 'other1.php'
    }

    if($li=='2'){
        include 'other2.php'
    }

}
```

other1.php :

```
<div id="otherdiv1">

 click functions to do something . Functions included in jquery defined in MainPage. 

</div>


<div id="otherdiv2">



</div>
```

The other1.php is listed properly in the Main Page but does not do the onclick functions unless jquery is included in other1.php too.

Including the jquery path and jquery scripts path in every page is making the response very slow.

Is there any easy way around this?

Comment: Put your JS and CSS includes in one php file and include it once in the beginning of every page instead of every php page. Or you can try require_once http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: @MoussaKhalil
  Do you mean like require_once('paths.php'); 

And in paths.php : 

    <?php
    echo "<link ref ... myfile.css> <script type='js' src='myfile.js'>";
    ?>

Wont this still include the JS in every page?

Comment: As stated in the manual: The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again. Even if you put it in every file, it will only trigger once

Comment: @MoussaKhalil I did that. The page loads fine. When I inspect it from Chrome dev tools, it shows the links are included again with the otherdiv1.php page, but it doesn't seem to tale any extra time to load the page. What does this mean?

Comment: @MoussaKhalil .. THanks a ton mate. You are a life saver. Your comment answered my question. I dont see any option to mark your comment as answer.

Comment: Add the answer and mark it as correct (you may need to wait 2 days for that)